# How to set Sublime Text to always use Tab Size: 2?

Tags: sublimetext

Yes, that is my question.

I know there is an editor config file you have to download on every project. But, is there a way to set Sublime Text to always use `Tab Size/Width: 2` and not `4`. Actually `4` is the default setting. But, how do I change that configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add `"tab_size": 2` to your user preferences. I suggest reading [this article](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html) to understand how Sublime Text does its settings and the order it consults settings files in.